# Regex to match only the forward slash

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to match the homepage in Analytics for a set of URLs using regex. The sample data looks like this:

```
/
/page1?u=test
/category/product.html
```

And I only need to match the first line (the `/`) character.

I tried `\/` but that doesn't work.

Comment: Use `^` and `$` as anchors: `/^\/$/`.

Comment: Maybe you can try `^\/.*`. This is bound to match *the first line* starting with `/`, whatever it may contain afterwards. If this is that part of GA where you cannot use `+` or `*` quantifiers, try just `^\/($|\r?\n)` to match the first line that only consists of `/`. Please let me know if my solution works for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `^` and `$` as anchors: `/^\/$/`.

- `^` means: start of string (or sometimes line)
- `$` means: end of string (or sometimes line)

#### Update:

The correct version for Analytics was `^\/$`.

Comment: Would be correct except that with GA table filters you must not use the /enclosing slashes/, so it's just ^\/$ (and if the homepage is occasinally called with query parameters those occurrences will be filtered out, too).

Comment: FYI (and further to @Eike's comment), the wrapping slashes have nothing whatsoever to do with regular expressions. Slashes are used by *some* languages (eg javascript) to *delimit* regexes, but are not *part* of the regex.